# scroll loop inside div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'd like to try to achieve an effect of loop scroll the page.
I found this script that to which I have made ​​some changes as the scroll 1px loading so as to enable the loop.

Should I apply this effect within a div ... but I can not figure out what to change the code to make it work.

It helped to turn the loop inside the wrapper div?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('body').height( WRHeight + $(window).height() );
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
        $(window).scrollTop(1);
    }
    else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
        $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
    }    
});
```

[loop div jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44pgr7gf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-implemented the script and added some comments to hopefully make it more clear:

```js
// Container element which has a scrollbar
var $c = $("#container");

// Child element which is taller than the container
var $e = $("#element");

// The point at which the page will loop when scrolling down
var loopPoint = $e.height() - $c.height();

// Define a function which runs whenever the scroll position of $c changes
$c.scroll(function () {

    // If the new scroll position matches our loop point
    if ($c.scrollTop() === loopPoint) {
        // Scroll to (almost) the the top ('0' would be the top; we do this so we don't loop back again instantly)
        $c.scrollTop(1);
    }

    // Otherwise, if the new scroll position = the top of the element
    else if ($c.scrollTop() === 0) {
        // Scroll to (almost) the bottom, we can use (our loop point - 1)
        $c.scrollTop(loopPoint - 1);
    }
});
```

Here's a JSfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/cjmoran/2do67um8/

Note: I've noticed that this approach can break middle-click scrolling in Chrome pretty badly, to the point that JSfiddle crashes. There may be a better way to implement this so that doesn't happen. Appears to work fine in the latest version of Firefox, but those are the only browsers I tested.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Unfortunately, I tried to implement your code, but it does not work....

http://jsfiddle.net/wg59cmxy/